# ArcGIS Arcade Labeling When Text Includes HTML Reserved Characters

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I am using the following expression in an ArcGIS feature label:

```
"(CH<SUB>4</SUB> " + $feature.Methane + " ppm)"
```

This works (e.g., CH<sub>4</sub> 15 ppm) unless the $feature.Methane value is "<1". In that case the result is

```
CH<SUB>4</SUB> <1 ppm
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: You have to HTML encode `<` to prevent it from being interpreted as an HTML control character.  Try:  `"(CH<SUB>4</SUB> " + Replace($feature.Methane,"<","&lt;") + " ppm)"`

Answer (score 1):

Some symbols such as `<`, `>` and `"` must be encoded similar to how it's done in XML or HTML. So rather than just typing the actual character, use `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;`

In your example:

```
CH<SUB>4</SUB> &lt;1 ppm
```

`lt` stands for *lesser than*, `gt` for *greater than*

Answer (score 0):

When using Arcade for labeling, the output is interpreted as HTML.  In this case, the [HTML reserved character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) `<` is in the field value, and its presence is messing up the HTML interpretation and display of the field value.

Knowing that Arcade labeling is interpreted as HTML, one can create a label expression that encodes the HTML reserved characters to their appropriate HTML entity.

```js
var htmlEncode = Dictionary(
    '"', "&quot;",
    "'", "&apos;",
    "&", "&amp;",
    "<", "&lt;",
    ">", "&gt;",
);

var rawString = "Value <1 or >5.  It's me.";

for(var char in htmlEncode) {
    rawString = Replace(rawString, char, htmlEncode[char]);
};

return rawString
```

returns

```js
Value &lt;1 or &gt;5.  It&apos;s me.
```